# Facebook no longer shows wedding and engagement notifications?

Tags: facebook

Facebook used to announce when our friends got engaged or married, and the messages appeared in the same areas as the birthday notifications. However, they seem to have disappeared some time ago; quite a few of my friends have gotten married in the past several months, and I only found out about the news by going to their profiles. Did Facebook remove this feature?

Comment: Have you been otherwise interacting with them? Actively liking or leaving comments on their updates?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook hasn't removed this 
[feature](https://www.facebook.com/help/390577744337750)

I believe if you go [here](https://www.facebook.com/events/list)  whilst signed in to facebook and click on the cog in the top right ( the one next to the word `Today`. Not the one on the main bar.)
Then tick /untick the box to your desired needs.